# Which tools can check for buffer overflows in a complete C project?

Tags: c, buffer-overflow

I need a tool to find possible buffer overflows in a C project. It should not only look for vulnerable functions like `strcpy()`, but also minimize the amount of false positives. For example a call like `strcpy(buffer,"")` should not be recognized as a buffer overflow and a good allocation of memory should be recognized as well.

Do you know a tool that fulfill these requirements?

I just found tools for single files (not a complete project) or they showed to many false positives.

Comment: For runtime checks you can use `valgrind`. I don't know if its possible for compiletime also.

Answer (score 2):

The [clang static analyser](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org) has many tests for bounds problems. You can use it on your entire project, by calling it as:

```
scan-build make
```

where "make" is the command that builds your project. It's quite conservative so you shouldn't get a lot of false positives.

Comment: tell that to my false positives

Comment: @tbert tell that to http://www.llvm.org/bugs/

Answer (score 2):

I found Gimpel's FlexeLint (Unix) == PC-Lint (Windows) a valuable tool for this type of checking. They have an [online demo checker](http://www.gimpel-online.com/OnlineTesting.html) where you can input your examples and see what warnings it generates. That should give you an idea of what it is capable of.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [KLEE, a symbolic virtual machine](http://klee.llvm.org/). It uses symbolic execution to determine all possible variable values on every possible execution path.

Comment: Oh, did they solve the Halting Problem too?

Comment: @ams: they don't have to if they don't guarantee that the analyzer will halt.

Comment: Okay, it **tries** to cover every possible execution path.

Answer (score 0):

Try [IBM Rational Purify](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/0822_satish-giridhar/); It is static code analyzer and see [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Purify) for more details.